# Google sheets script copying formatting *but not* merged cell status

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to write a script that copies the formatting, and the conditional formatting, that is applied to cell A1, and applies it to all of the other cells in the sheet.

*However*, I do not want to copy the merged-cell-status of A1.

For example, if A3 and B3 are merged, and if A1 is not merged with any other cell, then I want all of the formatting of A1 (both conditional and non-conditional) to be copied to the other cells, including A3 and B3, *but* in a way that preserves the merged status of A3 and B3 (or any other merged cells).

```
   A    B    C   
 _______________
1|   |    |    |
2|   |    |    |
3|        |    |
4|   |    |    |
```

I've tried the following functions, but both of these end up unmerging A3 and B3.

`function copyFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange('A1');
  var destination = ss.getRange('A2:A');
  source.copyTo(destination, {formatOnly:true});
}`

and

`function setFormat(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var firstCell = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1)
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange()
  firstCell.copyFormatToRange(sheet, 1, dataRange.getNumColumns(), 1, dataRange.getNumRows())
}`

Answer (score 2):

This works. It applies the formatting from cell `A1` to the rest of the cells in the spreadsheet upon any edit to those cells. See the commented lines for some configuration options:

```
function onEdit(e){           //This is activated each time a modification happens in the sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange(); // This is the fastest option; only the cells that have content are reformatted
  //var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns()); // This applies to all columns and rows in sheet, regardless of whether they have data; may slow things down
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()+2,sheet.getLastColumn()+2); // This applies the formatting to the active range with a 2 row and column buffer on all sides; hopefully not too slow

  var masterFormatCell = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1); // In this case, the Master Format Cell is A1 
  var mergedRanges = dataRange.getMergedRanges();    // Get list of merged ranges

  masterFormatCell.copyFormatToRange(sheet, 1, dataRange.getNumColumns(), 1, dataRange.getNumRows()); //Copy the Master Format Cell (i.e., A1) to the rest of the cells

  for (var i = 0; i < mergedRanges.length; i++) {    
    sheet.getRange(mergedRanges[i].getA1Notation()).merge(); // Re-merge the previously merged cells
  }
}
```